# How to repair a btrfs corrupt leaf

Tags: btrfs

I have a btrfs file system, where one directory causes an IO error no matter what I try to do with it:

- Listing its contents, or trying to remove it, causes an IO error, even as superuser:

  ```
  $ ls thedir 
  ls: cannot access 'thedir': Input/output error
  $ sudo rm -fr thedir 
  rm: cannot remove 'thedir': Input/output error
  ```
- Mounting a tmpfs over it causes an IO error:

  ```
  $ sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=10M tmpfs thedir
  mount: thedir: can't read superblock on tmpfs.
  ```

  I think "superblock *on* tmpfs" is misleading here, mounting a tmpfs over a different directory in the same file system works fine, and superblocks are a btrfs thing, not a tmpfs thing as far as I am aware.

The kernel logs say:

```
BTRFS critical (device sda1): corrupt leaf: root=5 block=46321315840 slot=24 ino=106823936, invalid inode generation: has 18446744073709551492 expect [0, 369151]
BTRFS error (device sda1): block=46321315840 read time tree block corruption detected
```

On the one hand it's good that btrfs detects the error and prevents worse problems, but now the entire filesystem is essentially spoiled. The bad directory is a problem, especially for rsync, which stops after the IO error.

**Is it possible to get *this* file system back into a usable state?** I have backups; I could create a new file system and copy over all the data if I need to, but it would take many days, maybe even weeks. I would much rather get rid of the corrupted directory, and restore only that part, which is much smaller.

I am using Linux 5.4.83 with `btrfs-progs` 5.9. I am aware of `btrfs check --repair`, but I am also aware of the warning in its man page:

> Do not use --repair unless you are advised to do so by a developer or an experienced user, and then only after having accepted that no fsck successfully repair all types of filesystem corruption. Eg. some other software or hardware bugs can fatally damage a volume.

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer?

Comment: Yes, I am still looking for an answer.

Comment: Its hard to give a specific suggestion without knowing your subvol layout and which subvol that dir is in. I would move everything but that dir into a separate subvol, then make the new subvol the default subvol and just mount that new subvol. Now the old subvol with the bad dir is effectively inaccessible from the mount point. Another trick I like to do when working on block devices where I might want to go back to the original state is to boot into a live cd and dm-snapshot the device and work on the snapshot until I'm confident I want to work on the real device.

Comment: As crass said.  Make sure to use "cp -iva --reflink=always" to minimize necessary time.  And after things are back working, just "btrfs sub delete" the old subvol.